# Can you use @Shared inside a method for Data Tables

Tags: spock

Shown below is a sample code.
Assume that "hi" and "hello" are complex objects and have to be evaluated inside the method.

The code below gives me:

> Process finished with exit code -1

Expected result is an "Unrolled" explanation of what passed and failed.

Code:

```
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

@Unroll
class DataTableTest extends Specification {

    def "#actual should equal #expected"() {
        @Shared def hi = "hi"
        @Shared def hello = "hello"

        expect:
        actual == expected

        where:
        actual | expected
        hi     | hi
        hi     | hello
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to define `@Shared` local variables like that. The `@Shared` annotation is only valid on fields or properties. If you move `hi` and `hello` outside of the feature method the test will execute.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can even define Shared vars inside a method as their purpose is to be reusable in other methods as they are high-cost calculated variables. Try to set up the shared variables in the class scope.